# including a partial in nested directories

Tags: javascript, ejs

If my folder structure is like this:

```
+--/views
  |
  +--partials/
  | |
  | +--messages.ejs
  | 
  |
  +--pages/
  | |
  | +--blog/
  | | |
  | | +--new.ejs
  | | +--show.ejs
  |
  |
  +--index.ejs
```

I can use <%= include('partials/messages'); %> in index.ejs, but not in new.ejs or show.ejs, otherwise I seem to get a "Could not find the include file "partials/messages" error. How can I fix this?

messages.ejs:

```
<% if(error_msg != ''){ %>
    <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= error_msg %>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: change the path of your include to `../../partials/messages`?

Comment: Yeah that worked, thank you lol. I kept trying to do ../views/partials/messages but it didn't work. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

change the path of your include to `../../partials/messages`

Comment: That worked, but the messages are just showing the code like: "<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"> You can't go there! <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button> </div>"

Comment: @ChanKim you might want to add that code snippet to the question. However if that is about something other than the include you may need to ask a new question

Comment: Okay, I edited my original post with what's in messages.ejs, and when I call it I just use req.flash('error_msg', "Error message here");. However, although your solution got rid of the original error saying it couldn't find the file, now it doesn't render the actual error message but shows the code instead

Comment: If this answer solved your original question you should mark it as the answer. that will help others as well. You are better of asking your second question is a new question as I have no experience with ejs